# Earliest moment to abandon POST request in webservice?

Tags: web-services, delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

One of the 'security measures' in my webservice is blocking large file uploads.
I want to cancel a file upload request ASAP when too large files are sent.

Since the requests with the file uploads are going to be the largest ones anyway, I currently have this code in the `BeforeDispatch` handler of the `TWebModule`:

```
procedure TWebModuleWebServices.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   // Request that are too large are going to be dropped silently:
   if Request.ContentLength > cMaxContentSize then
   begin
      Handled := true;
      Exit;
   end;
```

**Is the BeforeDispatch handler the earliest possible stage for this test, or is there a better place?**

The web service is built around a `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` (= `class(TIdCustomHTTPServer)`, see `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Indy, `TCustomWebDispatcher.BeforeDispatch` event is too late as the post data stream has already been retrieved in `TIdCustomHttpServer.DoExecute`. You can use `TIdCustomHTTPServer.OnHeadersAvailable` event - which is triggered earlier - to avoid it by setting `VContinueProcessing` to `False`.

Comment: When `OnHeadersAvailable` sets `VContinue=False`, you can then use the `TIdCustomHTTPServer.OnHeadersBlocked` event to customize the response that is sent back to the client.  By default, a `403 Forbidden` response is sent. In this case, `413 Payload Too Large` would be more appropriate.